# Kivy app for Android works for semi-random time and then freezes the self UI and Android UI causing phone reboot

Tags: android, kivy, python-multithreading

I read posts on this issues and adopted a threading mechanism, while making the UI update be called in the main thread.

But still the issues of freezing persists. I measured up time: if I use small buffers, the app works for 12 something minutes; with large buffers (5 times larger) the app works for 37 something minutes.

Didn't test it with the Bluetooth off on the phone, though.

In the code below the `accumulator` method which is being threaded takes about the same time as the `signaling` method. About 0.01 seconds. The later is a main thread one and saves a plot as a picture that appears on the box of the UI.

I noticed that seconds before the app freezes everything the period between UI updates grows (from 1 second as it was planned) to 2, 3, 10 seconds, and at this point all is unresponsive.

A code template of my program.

```
## Class of appication

class BiteSignal(App):
    
    def __init__(self, use_bluetooth, device_name, calibration_time_minutes, signal_sigmas, readings_per_minute):

        App.__init__(self)

        self.use_bluetooth = use_bluetooth

        if self.use_bluetooth:
            
            self.BluetoothAdapter = autoclass('android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter')
            self.BluetoothDevice = autoclass('android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice')
            self.BluetoothSocket = autoclass('android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket')
            self.InputStreamReader = autoclass('java.io.InputStreamReader')
            self.BufferedReader = autoclass('java.io.BufferedReader')
            self.UUID = autoclass('java.util.UUID')
            self.StringBuilder = autoclass('java.lang.StringBuilder')
        
        ### Etc.
    
    
    def connect_bt(self):
        
        status_label.text = 'Пытаюсь соединиться с блютусом...'

        paired_devices = self.BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBondedDevices().toArray()
        
        for self.device in paired_devices:
            
            if self.device.getName() == self.device_name:
                
                try:
                    
                    self.socket = self.device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(self.UUID.fromString('00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB'))

                    if not self.socket.connected:
                    
                        self.socket.connect()

                        return True

                except Exception as e:
                    
                    status_label.text = 'error: ' + str(e)
                    
                    return False

    
    def get_data(self):

        if not self.use_bluetooth: # use random data
            
            dat = random.randint(128, 1024)

            if dat > 1013:

                dat = random.randint(1024, 512000)

            return math.log(dat, 2)

        else: # use data from arduino
            
            if not self.socket.connected:
                
                self.connect_bt()
            
            try:
    
                bufferedreader = self.BufferedReader(self.InputStreamReader(self.socket.getInputStream(), 'US-ASCII'))
                
                input_read = bufferedreader.readLine().strip().rstrip()
    
                if input_read.isdigit():
    
                    if int(input_read) > 0:
                        
                        input_read_int = int(input_read)
                        
                        return math.log(input_read_int, 2)
    
                    else:
    
                        return None
                
                else:
                    
                    return None
            
            except Exception as e:
                
                status_label.text = 'Data error: ' + str(e)
    
                return None

    
    def buffer_start(self):

        # Data buffer
        
        self.accel_buffer = []
    
    
    def accumulator(self):

        ## A way to stop the thread

        thr = threading.currentThread()
        
        while getattr(thr, "do_run", True):
            
            dat = self.get_data()
            
            if dat is not None:
                
                ## Append to buffer and run some stats
    
            self.signaling() ### UI in main thread

            time.sleep(0.1) ### Data come at 0.1 second rate from the source
    
    
    @mainthread # decorator to manage UI
    def signaling(self):

        ### Procees data, apply stats, plot a chart, use all of these to update data in the UI


    
    def start_restart(self, instance): ## Used when Start button pressed

        if self.use_bluetooth:
            self.connect_bt()

        self.buffer_start()

        try:
            print('trying to stop existing thread')
            self.data_accumulator_thread.do_run = False
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        try:
            print('initiating thread')
            self.data_accumulator_thread = threading.Thread(target = self.accumulator)
            print('starting thread')
            self.data_accumulator_thread.start()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        
        action_button.text = 'Restart'
    
    
    def build(self):
        
        ### UI work with box layouts, labels and buttons
        
        return box_root
        

## Run
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    BS = BiteSignal(
        use_bluetooth = True,
        device_name = 'HC-06',
        calibration_time_minutes = 1,
        signal_sigmas = 5,
        readings_per_minute = 600
        )
    
    BS.run()
```

Comment: I would start debugging by adding a `print()` at the end of your `accumulator()` method (outside the loop) that lets you know the thread is actually ending. And perhaps some more debugging in the `start_restart()` method that prints a list of all the active threads.

Comment: @JohnAnderson, thank you. I added more prints and found that the restarting of the thread goes well. I found another reason for the issue: `RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. ` while using `matplotlib` to create and save charts. Guess I may have been creating hundreds of plot templates and overfilling RAM?

Comment: 10 minutes later... `import os, psutil; print(psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2)` Yep, it grows every second...

Answer (score 0):

I did not pay attention to some warnings, and in fact, they were the key.

```
RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened.
```

Inside the infinite loop of a pprogram I was creating pyplot templates every second, and each of them consumed RAM. So that after 30 minutes the app took a total of available RAM on the phome (about 6 gigabytes), causing the whole Android UI crash.

As a remedy, the creation of template became a single call in `__init__`:

```
self.plot = plt.figure(figsize = (4, 3), dpi = 100)
```

And the end of the plotting routine is ending with:

```
plt.cla()
plt.clf()
```

After doing that prints of consumed memory

```
import os, psutil; print(psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2)
```

showed no growth, and the app was tested and showed stability for more than an hour (which is enough).